# What variables are available in extension scope (like window, gBrowser)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I know about `window`, `gBrowser`, `gContextMenu` and some more but what are all global variables available to Firefox extensions?

Comment: The JS shell that comes with the Extension Developer extension can list them all for you. I don't have it installed (it seems like it causes funky things to happen on Fx 4) and I don't remember the exact command, but I want to say it's something like `props(window)`

Comment: @MatrixFrog - Thanks, good suggestion. I have already installed it but it seems that it's not running in chrome (unlike extension). Should I look inside to find out how props or auto-complete works and copy it to my extension to extract variables or do you have any other idea?

Comment: Again, I forget the exact command, but there's something you can click at the top to list all the possible execution contexts. One will be browser.xul and if you click on that it will switch so that `window` will be the browser.xul window.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - Yes that's `enumerateWindows()`! Please add you comments as answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the JS shell in [Extension Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/extension-developer/). Click `enumerateWindows()` and then `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`. Then type `props(window)` to see all the global variables (since global variables in JavaScript are really just properties of `window`. Note however that there have been some reports of Extension Developer causing weird stuff to happen on Firefox 4.

Comment: Thanks, by the way it can also be `props(this)`.